# Dual monitor setup, windows are switched around when connecting HDMI TV

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors

I have [this setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hcoo.png), 2 permanent DVI monitors and a optional HDMI TV. It automatically (dis)connects when turning the TV on/off, but my windows are shuffled around every time I do and don't stay on the same monitor as before. I'm using Windows 8.1 and have a AMD Radeon R7 2xx.

How can I solve this problem?